# Can't pick up data from database

Tags: php, database, html, mysqli, content-management-system

I am trying to build up a system where I have web pages content generated by a user in a form, saved in a database, make a list of all the pages existing in the database and by clicking on that list editing the desired page.

The only thing that is not working is the editing part. It seems that I cannot grab the data from the database because when I click on a page to edit, the "template" has nothing in the forms.

Here is the code:

**Page with the list of pages existing on the database:**

```
<?php
    require_once "../scripts/conector.php";

    if (!$_GET['pid']) {
    $pageid = '1';
    } else {
        $pageid = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['pid']); 
    }

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, producent FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($myConnection)); 

    $producentnamn = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $producent = $row["producent"];
        $producentnamn .= '<a href="edit_page.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $producent . '</a>';
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query);
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="edit_page.php">
    <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" class="botao" value="Redigera" />
    <input name="pid" type="text" id="pid" value="<?php echo $producentnamn; ?>"/>
</form>
```

**edit_page.php**

```
<?php
    $pid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_POST['pid']);  

    include_once "../scripts/conector.php";
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT pagetitle, linklabel, evenemang, presentation, producent, pagebody, mapa FROM pages WHERE id='$pid' LIMIT 1";  
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $pagetitle = $row["pagetitle"];
        $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];
        $evenemang = $row["evenemang"];
        $presentation = $row["presentation"];
        $producent = $row["producent"];
        $pagebody = $row["pagebody"];
        $mapa = $row["mapa"];
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query);
?>

<label>Map</label>
<textarea name="mapa" id="mapa"><?php echo $mapa; ?></textarea>
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
<input name="pid" type="text" id="pid" value="<?php echo $producentnamn; ?>"/>
```

to

```
<input name="pid" type="text" id="pid" value="<?php echo $pid; ?>"/>
```

Because you are passing `<a href="edit_page.php?pid=' . $pid . '">` to the form. which I think doesnt exist in the db. You got to pass the value/id of the page to the form.

Comment: But if I echo the $pid, I will lose the list with the name of each created page and have instead the ID...

Comment: in your edit_page.php you are using $pid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_POST['pid']); So edit_page.php is expecting a pid not an anchor tag. If you pass the value as anchor tag then the query will be SELECT pagetitle, linklabel, evenemang, presentation, producent, pagebody, mapa FROM pages WHERE id='<a href="edit_page.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $producent . '</a>' LIMIT 1 . You think whis will give you your result?

Comment: try using <input name="pid" type="text" id="pid" value='<?php echo $pid; ?>'/>. Notice the single quotes instead of double quotes